# Getting users from a group as a paging result using the AuthorityService in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco

Is it possible to get the users from an Alfresco group as a paging result by using the `AuthorityService` in Alfresco from Java code?

I have been looking at the methods of the `AuthorityService` but I cannot find an appropriate method to do this. The methods that come closest to what I need are these two:

```
public PagingResults<String> getAuthorities(
    AuthorityType type,
    String zoneName,
    String displayNameFilter,
    boolean sortByDisplayName,
    boolean sortAscending,
    PagingRequest pagingRequest
);
```

and

```
public Set<String> getContainedAuthorities(
    AuthorityType type,
    String name,
    boolean immediate
);
```

The former method can provide a paging result as needed, but not for a specific group only, and the latter can provide the users for a specific group but not as a paging result. Is there a way in which I can get the combined functionality of these two methods, i.e. get the users in a given group as a paging result?

Comment: Why do you need a paging result set? What's wrong with calling a method that'll just give you the whole lot in one go?

Comment: There are too many users (~1500) in the group, i.e. the webscript from which I will be calling the method in the `AuthorityService` is responding too slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use existing REST API? If you can't do this because of whatever reason, you can always see how this was implemented and see if you can learn something out of it.

Hope it helps.

https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/RESTful-GroupsChildrenGet.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I can't use the REST API since I will be enriching the users with some extra metadata that is not provided by the REST API. The relevant endpoint that you are referring to is implemented in JavaScript, and I guess the necessary root objects in JavaScript is using the Java services in some way (is this correct?), i.e. I don't think that I will gain anything in performance (which is needed due to the large amount of users) by making an equivalent implementation in JavaScript. But I will see if I can find out how the JavaScript root objects are implemented.